# How to add php zip to server, I'm using wordpress on google cloud platform

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, terminal, php-ziparchive

I have loaded wordpress on the google cloud platform and I am trying to transfer my wordpress site on my local to google.  When I was loading the file it gave me the error message "Install a PHP zip on your server or contact your site host."

I saw a few fixes to install sudo apt install php-zip.  I'm assuming I have to connect the google cloud platform to my terminal and then run that, but I do not know how to connect the two.

Edit:  I have added a snapshot of the software that is being used

[image]

Comment: Transferring your Wordpress site is easier to transfer manually IMO ..  `tar.gz` your html directory, mysql dump your database.  Then create the new database on your new server, create the user specified in your wp-config file and give it permissions to said database .. Other than small issues, nuances -- it should just "work"

Comment: If you do not understand the details on how to move WordPress, use a plugin such as **All-in-One WP MIgration**. However, I do not recognize your error message. Edit your question with details on how your system is configured.

Comment: The first item I recommend is to learn how to SSH into your server and **read** the Apache log files. This will help you debug problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced a similar error before and I used the **Wordpress** provided by **Google Click to Deploy**. There are other fixes depending on the configuration of your web server and its hosting. But here is the simple fix I have done to remove the error on my end.

1. Go to **Compute Engine** > **VM Instance**
2. Click the **SSH** button to open a connection to your Host machine.
3. A new black window will appear[terminal], Then type the following:

> ```
> sudo apt install php-zip
> sudo service apache2 restart
> ```

If you are using a different configuration, you can update your post with more details such as **web server platform** used, **PHP Version**, **Marketplace Product** (if taken from GCP Marketplace) and Server **OS Model and version** for us to be able to help you further.

Comment: I have edited the original post that include the software that is being used.  I was able to get the terminal to pull up and run the request.  But I'm not sure that it did anything, it still will not allow me to upload zip files

Comment: Thanks I was able to get this to work by using sudo apt-get install php7.4-zip and sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into the same issue while trying to set up WordPress in
Google Cloud app engine. I tried

- sudo apt-get install php7.4-zip
- sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

It fixed the file extension problem I was running into.

Comment: I used this and it worked for me as well. I'm running the default WordPress deployment provided by the Google Tutorial in Console.